# Jboss Hibernate Tools: Reading error schema - Probably a JDBC driver Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, reverse-engineering

Hello i am trying to use JBoss Hibernate Tools for Reverse  engineering. I am using `eclipse luna` and latest hibernate jboss tools from eclipse market place. When i trying to configure the hibernate tools configuration, After configuration done, when i expand the tree and expand `database` node, it generate an following error:

```
<Reading Schema Error: Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database. Probably a JDBC Driver Problem>
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not get list of suggested identity strategies from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem. 
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.MySQLMetaDataDialect.getSuggestedPrimaryKeyStrategyName(MySQLMetaDataDialect.java:55)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processPrimaryKey(JDBCReader.java:429)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:238)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-empirecl-test  like 'oauth_access_token'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
```

My database connection with eclipse is build successfully beacause with the help of `Database explore` by eclipse make connection successfully and also display all tables. I am using `Hibernate 4.3` and latest `MySQL driver 5.1.31`. Following are the screen shots of my configuration.

1. [image]
2. [image]

Following is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nit-empirecl-test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, The problem is with database name. I don't know, but hibernate jboss tool, not support `( - )` Hyphen in database name. When i change the name with underscore the configuration will run successfully.

Comment: I went through the same issue with a database in postgresql. I had 3 schemas. The schema that contains tables with underscore is not recognized by Hibernate (i.e. employee_organization). At the beginning I only had one schema where all the tables contained underscore in the table names. Hibernate got connected and listed all the tables but it never generated the classes. I tested a new schema with tables w/o underscore and Hibernate generated all the classes (pojos). And when I had 2 schemas, the previous with underscored tables doesn't load anymore. Big deal.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the `hibernate` default schema (for sql server)

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
```

Comment: Thank you. That tag example throws an error in my case but `<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbo" />` didn't which is practically the same

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with MS SQL Server and without "-" in DB name. 
You can try to set the "optional" property hibernate.default_schema.